# AngularJS Ui-Router: Back button Transition Error

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic-view

Currently I'm using states in my Ionic Framework App. When I press the back button to return to a previous state it shows the current state and the state that it should transition to in the same screen.

**Error Screen:**

[image]

Each Individual Screen Looks like this:

**Screen 1:**

[image]

**Screen 2:**

[image]

On transition from **Screen 1** back button to **Screen 2** the error screen occurs.

In my configuration file the current setup is as such:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })
  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:
  .state('tab.events', {
    url: '/events',
    views: {
      'tab-event': {
        templateUrl: 'views/events.html',
        controller: 'EventsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('tab.event-detail',{
    url:'/events/:eventId',
        views: {
          'tab-event':{
            templateUrl: 'views/event.html',
            controller: 'EventDetailsCtrl'
          }
        }
  })
      .state('tab.attendees',{
        url: '/events/:eventId/attendees/:attendeeIds',
        views: {
          'tab-event':{
            templateUrl: 'views/attendees.html',
            controller: 'AttendeesCtrl'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('tab.attendee-detail',{
        url: '/events/:eventId/attendee/:attendeeId',
        views: {
          'tab-event':{
            templateUrl: 'views/attendee.html',
            controller: 'AttendeeDetailCtrl'
          }
        }
      });
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
});
```

When i press the back button From the **'tab.attendees'** state back to the **'tab.event-detail'** state the error occurs. If it helps I transition from 'tab.event-detail' state to 'tab.attendees' state via anchor tag like so:

```
<a ng-href="#/tab/events/{{event.id}}/attendees/{{event.attendees}}">See Attendees</a>
```

What could be causing the screen mix?

Comment: does this happen in android? ios? on a emulator? using serve?

Comment: @JessPatton This happens in chrome on the desktop, using serve. It also happens in IOS when I test it on a device.

Comment: okay are you using the latest version of ionic and cordova?

Comment: @JessPatton Yes both are the latest version. Could it be the way that I'm nesting the states?